# Merge two dataframes to one in pandas

Tags: pandas

I have two dataframes

df_a

```
|id    |name|    email|
|0   | Jack  |  jack@gmail.com|
|1   | James |   james@gmail.com|
|2   | Alice |   alice@gmail.com|
```

df_b

```
|id    |name|    email|
|2   | Alice |  alice@live.com    |
|3   | Allen |   allen@gmail.com   |
|4   | Amy   | amy@gmail.com       |
```

I want to merge two dataframe base on id,and using df_a's email .get result like this:

df_result

```
|id    |name|    email|
|0    |Jack |   jack@gmail.com  |
|1    |James|    james@gmail.com|
|2    |Alice|    alice@gmail.com|
|3    |Allen|    allen@gmail.com|
|4    |Amy  |  amy@gmail.com    |
```

It is a little different like this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21317384/pandas-python-how-to-concatenate-two-dataframes-without-duplicates) ,because id=2 **Alice**'s email is different.

Comment: It seems you need to become a bit better at googling.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) + [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) with specify columns for check dupes:

```
df = pd.concat([df_a, df_b]).drop_duplicates(['id','name'])
print (df)
   id   name            email
0   0   Jack   jack@gmail.com
1   1  James  james@gmail.com
2   2  Alice  alice@gmail.com
1   3  Allen  allen@gmail.com
2   4    Amy    amy@gmail.com
```