# Append Data Frame in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, loops, append

I have multiple sheets that are identical in column headers but not in terms of the number of rows. I want to combine the sheets to make one master sheet.

At the moment this is the code that I get, for which the output is blank and I end up with `data` = to that in the last sheet.

I decided to utilise a for loop iterated through `data_sheetnames` which is a list.

Below is the code I have utilised

```
combineddata = pd.DataFrame()
for club in data_sheetnames:
    data = pd.read_excel(r'''C:\Users\me\Desktop\Data.xlsx''', header = 1, index_col = 2, sheet_name = club)
    combineddata.append(data)
```

If I were to change combineddata to a blank list then I get a dictionary of dataframes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas/Python: How to concatenate two dataframes without duplicates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21317384/pandas-python-how-to-concatenate-two-dataframes-without-duplicates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is that append does not work in place.
It returns the appended DataFrame.
Therefore

```
combineddata = pd.DataFrame()
for club in data_sheetnames:
    data = pd.read_excel(r'''C:\Users\me\Desktop\Data.xlsx''', header = 1, index_col = 2, sheet_name = club)
    combineddata = combineddata.append(data)
```

should solve the issue

Comment: Thanks, this has solved the query. I can only accept in 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

An easier way is just to do this:

```
combined_data = pd.concat([pd.read_excel(sheet_name) for sheet_name in data_sheetnames])
```