# Python DataFrames: Appending dataframes or series and overwriting by index

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, append

I will have an iterating process creating a set of similar, but not identical pandas series by index.

I want to append one to the other but overwrite where applicable. eg

Series One:

```
Index Value
Jan    3
Feb    5
Mar    4
```

Series Two:

```
Index Value
Mar    10
Apr    5
May    7
```

Desired Output:

```
Jan    3
Feb    5
Mar    10
Apr    5
May    7
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can append dataframes. I found this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21317384/pandas-python-how-to-concatenate-two-dataframes-without-duplicates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us do

```
s=s2.combine_first(s1)
Index
Apr     5.0
Feb     5.0
Jan     3.0
Mar    10.0
May     7.0
Name: Value, dtype: float64
```

Or

```
s1.append(s2).groupby(level=0).tail(1)
Index
Jan     3
Feb     5
Mar    10
Apr     5
May     7
Name: Value, dtype: int64
```