# Merge tables with index column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, join, merge, multi-index

I need to join two tables:

[image]

[image]

I use the next code:

```
    table = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['user-reference_id'], how = 'right')
```

But it doesn´t work. I have obtained duplicated values.

The result i need to obtain is:

| user-reference_id | reference_date | first_purchase | month |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 159 | 2019-06-14 | 62.95 | 6 |
| 5009 | 2017-10-19 | 58.50 | 10 |
| 5026 | 2017-07-04 | 35.52 | 7 |
| 5032 | 2017-01-02 | 71.68 | 1 |

Comment: Does user-reference_id appear multiple times in one or both of your dataframes?  If so, then you are getting back a cartisean product of records.

Comment: I have user-reference_id in both dataframes and i need to join two tables by user-reference_id. In the last table i have reference_date as index and when i join two tables i get duplicates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit: I misunderstood your case so I have changed my answer.**

The type of merge to be performed is wrong. You need to change your keyword argument on the [how](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html?highlight=merge#pandas.DataFrame.merge) parameter. Change it to:

```
table = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['user-reference_id'], how='outer')
```

There are a couple of links that are related e.g. :

[Difference(s) between merge() and concat() in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38256104/differences-between-merge-and-concat-in-pandas)

[Pandas/Python: How to concatenate two dataframes without duplicates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21317384/pandas-python-how-to-concatenate-two-dataframes-without-duplicates)

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html#

Comment: @new_datascientist I have found a great article, which explains the how parameter. I think the documentation is not explaining it in an understandable way. See https://realpython.com/pandas-merge-join-and-concat/