# Match two pandas data frames using one column in one data frame as default

Tags: python, pandas, merge, grouping, multiple-columns

I have say 2 data frames as below:

```
 df1 

    A    B    C
    1    a    X
    1    b    Y
    1    c    U
    2    d    T
    3    k    Z
```

And 2nd data frame say as

```
  df2 

    A   B     C
    1   a     M1
    1   d     K
    2   d     Fr
    7   y     Io
```

So the way we need to do the merge is if the col A and Col B values match in both data frames then data frame 1 gets priority if not then individual data frame data gets the input.

So the output looks like;

```
  Outdf 

    A    B    C
    1    a    X
    1    b    Y
    1    c    U
    1    d    K
    2    d    T
    3    k    Z
    7    y    Is
```

I tried using merge on left but is not able to achieve, because when not totally matched it gives null or blank. How to avieve my result?.  Any help please?

Comment: `pd.concat([df1, df2]).drop_duplicates(subset=['A', 'B'], keep='first')` (optionally with an extra sorting step)

Comment: @mozway - I think this is an excellent (and simple) answer - Certainly worth writing up properly instead of just as a comment

Comment: @SimonPratt this is already in the [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21317570/16343464), I just wrote it here for convenience.